# how to sync ftp folder with local folder?

Tags: sync, ftp

I have a local folder, and I would like to sync it a folder on a web server via FTP . what is the best way to accomplish this? I would prefer to be able to do this via terminal, so that I can just have an 'update' command that would update the files on the sever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could mount it with `curlftpfs` and then sync it with `unison`.

Comment: ... or `rsync` (which is used by `unison`)

Comment: `rsync` does not sync in two ways I think.

Comment: No, it doesn't. But for this case it is not necessarily needed. I just wanted to add it ;)

Comment: Right, in this case a `rsync --delete` would do the trick.

Comment: A good tutorial on how to do that (it's not that complex, but it helps to have a guideline): https://www.raphael.li/tips/synchronize-ftp/

Answer (score 1):

The script you are searching for might be [FTPSync](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/ftpsync/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I see that it would make sense in general, but in this case I recommend a program. What else should I write? Type "ftpsync.pl -h" to learn how to use it.

Comment: The page moved to https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/ftpsync/ and there's a git repository : https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/ftpsync.git